# Can someone identify these fungi?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Found them in Gujarat, India.
Found growing among potted plants
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be *Clitocyte odora* commonly known as aniseed toadstool.

> They can be found growing in small groups along the side of tree roots.

> it is widespread in the temperate zones, occurring in **Asia**, Europe, and North America

> Young specimens have a light blue texture on the cap which fades to grey in age. The gills and stem are white with no ring.

[image]

[Reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitocybe_odora)

Answer (score -1):

If there is a white skirt it is probably a verdigris argaric:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stropharia_aeruginosa